# Is there a command to restart a while loop?

Tags: python

Is there a command to restart a while loop? I am creating a guessing game but i need to find a way to restart the loop.

```
import random
from random import randrange

run = True
turns = 0
while run is True:
    number = randrange(1, 11)
    guess = int(input("Guess a number from 1 to 10: "))
    turns += 1
    if guess == number:
        print("You Won!")
        break
    else:
        print("Try again.")
    if turns == 3:
        print("You lost")
        break
restart = input("Would you like to play again?(y/n) ")
if restart.lower() == "y":
    # How do i restart the loop???
else:
    print("Goodbye!")
```

Comment: I would put the "game logic" into a function then put that into a while loop with your question (i.e. function call, followed by question, with the while loop dependent on the answer to the question)

Comment: put it in other `while True` loop and external `while` loop will repeate internal `while` loop. And use `break` to exit external loop  - `if restart.lower() != "y": break`